# Proof: If a ≡ b (mod n) then am ≡ bm (mod mn) and converse

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Prove the following, for positive integers m and n.

If $a \equiv b \pmod n$ then $am \equiv bm \pmod{mn}$ and conversely,
If $am \equiv bm \pmod{mn}$ then $a \equiv b \pmod n$.

This makes sense to me logically. And I believe that this has something to do with the definition of multiples or divisors in modular arithmetic. 
Since $a - b$ is a multiple of $n$. Something along the lines of then also $am - bm $would be a multiple of $mn$. I'm not sure if the steps would be reversible so that I could also prove the converse.

However, I do not not know how to formalize this proof, or starting steps. Thank you for any help and support.

Comment: Use the definition of $x\equiv y\ (\mod\ mn)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a ≡ b\mod n$ ⇒  $a=k.n +b$ ⇒ $ am=k(nm)+mb$ ⇒ $am≡mb \mod nm$

Do reverse operation for reverse:

$am≡mb \mod nm$ ⇒ $ am=k(nm)+mb$ ⇒  $a=k.n +b$ ⇒$a ≡ b\mod n$

Answer (score 2):

if $a-b$ is a multiple of $n$, it means there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a-b = kn$, you just have to **multiply** by $m$ to get the result.

Hint:

To solve the converse. think of what is the reverse operation of multiplication. Note that $m$ is positive.

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1,**
If a ≡ b (mod n) then we can say that n | a - b.
So a - b = kn (k ∈ Z)
Multiplying m in both sides we get, am - bm = mnk
So, mn | am - bm.
This implies, a ≡ b (mod mn)
**Part 2**
if am ≡ bm (mod mn),
(am - bm) = mnx (x ∈ Z)
or, m(a - b) = mnx
or, (a - b) = nx
This implies, n | (a - b) or a ≡ b (mod n)
Proved!