# Prooving the possibilty of factor cancelation in a congruence equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How can one prove that $a*c \equiv b*c \:\: mod(n*c)$ equals $ a \equiv b \: \: mod(n)$, the only thing I know thus far is that factor cancellation is only allowed if gcd(a,n)=1 i.e when a and n are relatively prime. I thought that using a Direct Proof would be the easiest way so we assume our first congruence and than try to get to our second congruence via arithmetic manipulations.

Comment: In order to help you prove what you say you know we need to know where you are starting. If you [edit] the question to tell us how you might start this proof we may be able to help. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show some personal  work.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883921/242) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1883921/242) and *many* others. It's best for site health to delete this question.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so after thinking a little bit more about the problem my answer to the question would be as follows:

We can write $$a*c \equiv b*c \: \: mod(c*n)$$ as $$(a*c-b*c)=k*(n*c), k \in \mathbb Z$$

So now we have a ordinary equation where we can just cancel out the factor c via division on the left and right hand side and end up with $$k*n = a-b$$  which in turn is equal to $$ a\equiv b \: \: mod(n)$$ and this basically concludes the proof because one has shown that the first congruence equation is equal to the second. Would this be somewhat acceptable as prove?

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. Moreover, we should anyway not edit more answers to such a megaduplicate. See for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641382 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1883921

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).